# How do I delete every row except the last one for each day?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with stock quotes that looks something like this:

id, date, stock_id, value

Every day has several rows for each stock_id (it is automatically updated every five minutes), so the table is rather big at the moment.

How do i delete every row but the last one each day for every stock_id?

Comment: Is date actually a datetime or a pure date?

Comment: Is the last row determined by the last datestamp of the day?  Is the date a DateTime timestamp?

Answer (score 10):

The other answers don't make sure to keep at least one record per `stock_id` per day.  The following should do what you want.

```
DELETE FROM StockQuotes
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM StockQuotes
    GROUP BY stock_id, DATE(`date`)
)
```

Assuming `id` is a sequentially auto-numbered field, and `date` is a datetime field that at least contains the date, but my contain hour, minute, second, etc. as well.

Comment: It is indeed a datetime field. should i change to GROUP BY DATE(date) or do i need to make some other changes?

Comment: @A no problem - I've made a change that should support your datetime field.

Comment: Cant you just do MAX(date) ? that would bring up the last time of each day, i guess this would be slower than just using ID

Comment: @Spidfire MAX(date) will just return the most-recently-entered row, period.  I suppose you could do `DELETE FROM StockQuotes WHERE date NOT IN ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM StockQuotes GROUP BY stock_id, DATE(date))`, but then you have the possibility that records for stocks A and B were entered at the same time (part of a batch process, maybe), and that's the most recent row for stock A, but another record for stock B was entered the same day.  In that situation, this'll result in two rows being left for stock B for that day, which we don't want.

Comment: Is this a query that should take a reeeeally long time to execute? I can't get it to work. No error or anything, it just keeps loading.

Comment: @A It shouldn't, no.  What may be happening is that it's recomputing the list of MAX(id) each deletion - which makes sense, since you're modifying the underlying table.  Consider creating a temporary table `temp(id int)` and running the parenthetical query from above to populate it.  Then you can just `delete from stockquotes where id not in (select id from temp)`

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do what you want:

```
DELETE FROM STOCK_QUOTES
  WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID
                     FROM STOCK_QUOTES
                     GROUP BY DATE, STOCK_ID));
```

Comment: As with John Rasch's answer, this will discard all but the largest `stock_id` for each `date`, which is incorrect - it should discard all but the largest `id` for each `stock_id` for each `date`.